# Ordenação de vetor de objetos

Tags: c++, classes, vector

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que ordena um vetor de objetos. Esses objetos são pontos cartesianos, definidos na seguinte classe:

```
class CartesianPoint {
private:
    int x; // Coordinate X of a pin or a wire part on a cartesian plan
    int y; // Coordinate Y of a pin or a wire part on a cartesian plan

public:
    CartesianPoint();
    CartesianPoint(const CartesianPoint& orig);
    virtual ~CartesianPoint();

    int getX() const {
        return x;
    }

    int getY() const {
        return y;
    }

    CartesianPoint(int x, int y) :
    x(x), y(y) {
    }
```

Para fazer a ordenação, estou usando a função sort da seguinte maneira:

```
int main() 
{
    int i;
    CartesianPoint *a = new CartesianPoint(10, 13), *b = new CartesianPoint(32, 1), *c = new CartesianPoint(5, 29), *d = new CartesianPoint(12, 6), *e = new CartesianPoint(21, 100);
    CartesianPoint myPoints[] = {*a, *b, *c, *d, *e};

    std::vector<CartesianPoint> myvector(myPoints, myPoints+8);        

    // using function as comp
    std::sort(myvector[0], myvector.end(), myfunction); 

    // print out content:
    std::cout << "myvector contains:";
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        std::cout << ' ' << '(' << myvector[i].getX() << ',' << myvector[i].getY() << ')';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

onde "myfunction" é a função que ordena os pontos de forma decrescente em relação ao x:

```
CartesianPoint* myfunction(CartesianPoint *a, CartesianPoint *b) {
    if(a->getX() > b->getX())
        return (a);
    else
        return (b);
}
```

O problema que está dando é na chamada da função `sort`:

```
sort.cpp:33:5: error: no matching function for call to 'sort'
    std::sort(myvector[0], myvector.end());
```

O que está pode estar errado?

Comment: Cadê os includes? Edite seu código aqui e mostre-nos, por favor!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Respondendo a pergunta:

> O problema que está dando é na chamada da função sort:

A função [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) é do tipo *Comparable* e deve retornar um valor do tipo `bool` (e não um ponteiro para a classe *CartesianPoint*).

---

Ainda existem outros problemas no programa, como, por exemplo, o array de referências, que pode ser trocado por um array de ponteiros.

Segue uma versão funcional com poucas modificações:

```
class CartesianPoint {
private:
    int x; // Coordinate X of a pin or a wire part on a cartesian plan
    int y; // Coordinate Y of a pin or a wire part on a cartesian plan

public:
    CartesianPoint() {}

    CartesianPoint(const CartesianPoint& orig)
    {}

    CartesianPoint(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y)
    {
    }

    virtual ~CartesianPoint()
    {}

    int getX() const {
        return x;
    }

    int getY() const {
        return y;
    }

};

// Aqui => a função retorna um boolean
bool myfunction(CartesianPoint *a, CartesianPoint *b) {
    return a->getX() < b->getX();
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    CartesianPoint *a = new CartesianPoint(10, 13), 
        *b = new CartesianPoint(32, 1), 
        *c = new CartesianPoint(5, 29), 
        *d = new CartesianPoint(12, 6), 
        *e = new CartesianPoint(21, 100);

    // Aqui => trocado para ponteiros e não referências!!
    CartesianPoint *myPoints[] = { a, b, c, d, e };

    // O vetor é de ponteiros!
    std::vector<CartesianPoint *> myvector(myPoints, myPoints + sizeof(myPoints) / sizeof(myPoints[0]));

    // using function as comp
    // O primeiro parâmetro é um iterator => begin()
    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction);

    // print out content:
    std::cout << "myvector contains:";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        std::cout << ' ' << '(' << myvector[i]->getX() << ',' << myvector[i]->getY() << ')';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Bom, dando uma pesquisada por alto aqui, vi que já houve vários desses problemas e suas respostas aqui mesmo no SO, a mais completa que achei é essa aqui:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814618/no-matching-function-for-call-to-sort

O problema é bem simples. A função que você escolheu usar é essa:

```
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

Porém essas variáveis `first` e `last` esperam **Iteradores** para percorrer a sua coleção, visto que essa função é implementada como template para aceitar vários tipos de coleções. O seu `last`está certo, só que o `first` está errado, você não passou o iterador e sim o elemento. Corrija e coloque o seguinte:

```
std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction);
```

Isso está na própria documentação: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

E também, sua função `myfunction` retorna um ponteiro para o seu objeto, sendo que tem que retornar um valor do tipo `bool`, porque é uma função de comparação. Você deve corrigir também:

```
bool myfunction(CartesianPoint &a, CartesianPoint &b)
{
   return a.getX() < b.getX();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Parece conversão de um programa de C# para C++...

Abaixo uma versão C++11 corrigida, retirando os C#ismos:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <algorithm>
using std::sort;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class CartesianPoint
{
   private:
      int x;
      int y;

   public:
      int getX() const { return x; }
      int getY() const { return y; }
      CartesianPoint(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
};

static bool myfunction(const CartesianPoint& a, const CartesianPoint& b)
{
   return a.getX() < b.getX();
}

int main() 
{
   vector<CartesianPoint> myvector { {10, 13}, {32, 1}, {5, 29}, {12, 6}, {21, 100} };

   sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction); 

   cout << "myvector contains:";

   for (const auto& point : myvector)
       cout << ' ' << '(' << point.getX() << ',' << point.getY() << ')';

   cout << '\n';
}
```

ideone.com: http://ideone.com/wDSIV0

Abaixo uma versão para C++14:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <algorithm>
using std::sort;

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class CartesianPoint
{
   private:
      int x;
      int y;

   public:
      int getX() const { return x; }
      int getY() const { return y; }
      CartesianPoint(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
      bool operator< (const CartesianPoint& that) const { return x < that.x; }

};

int main() 
{
   vector<CartesianPoint> myvector { {10, 13}, {32, 1}, {5, 29}, {12, 6}, {21, 100} };

   auto cmpFunc = [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) { return p1 < p2; };
   sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), cmpFunc); 

   cout << "myvector contains:";

   for (const auto& point : myvector)
       cout << ' ' << '(' << point.getX() << ',' << point.getY() << ')';

   cout << '\n';
}
```

ideone.com: http://ideone.com/v3fSdV

That's it.